# Inverse scaling output data with different dimension from the input

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am using a neural network (supervised learning) to train an agent in Safety-Gym.
After collecting data I need to scale and devide them in input-target.
I perform the scaling on the entire dataset:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(Dataset)
scaler.transform(Dataset)
```

and then i devide my dataset in input-target using slicing on the Dataset(numpy array).

I dont'think I need to inverse transform my output during training (i.e when I compute the loss function) but I think i need to inverte it when I want to act on the environment.
The problem is that the output has different dimension from the dataset so I can't use the inverse_transform method.

What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You´re right. You don´t need to inverse transform during training.

After learning and training the model, you should use the same scaler to inverse transform your prediction result so that you can compare it with your true data.

Finally, you should use the scaler for the new incoming data when you deploy your model.

Tips: you can use

```
scaler.fit_transform() 
scaler.inverse_transform()
```

See more: [standard_scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler)

Comment: My dataset has n row and 101 columns while the output of my network has n row and 98 columns.
I was wondering if, not being able to use the Inverse_Transform function given the different dimensions, it makes sense to access to the Scaler object and take the mean and the STD deviation of the 98 columns and then manually calculate the reverse transformation. I hope that I have been clear :D

Comment: I have encountered the same problem before. I simply make sure they have the same shape by adding another columns of zeros. Note that the scaler works per column so it will not be a problem if you add columns with any values nor if there's difference in your number of rows.